# Odd many-to-many form rendering with symfony and doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm hoping this is possible using some built-in libraries such as the form builder. I have the following three entities. The one in the middle is almost just a regular join table but it has an extra column with an extra piece of data.

Formula --< FormulaColor >-- Color

FormulaColor has the fields: formula, color, and percentage.

The percentage field is to say what percentage a color makes up of a given formula. A very simple example is that a Formula may be 77% red and 33% blue. My problem is that I want to choose the colors for a Formula, and give them a percentage manually using forms. So I would add (or edit) a certain formula and give it say the color violet (20%) green (45%) and yellow (35%). I do not care about being able to add new colors in the formula add/edit view. I just want to be able to select existing colors. I've been playing around with it for hours with collection and entity types, but no luck.

Got any pointers or tips for me? Will I have to do it manually without the form component etc?

Thanks.

**formula form type**

```
class FormulaAddEditType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('code', null, array(
                    'label' => 'Code'
                ))
            ->add('name', null, array(
                    'label' => 'Name'
                ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\Formula'
            ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'prism_portal_adminbundle_formulaaddedittype';
    }
}
```

**Formula Entity**

```
class Formula
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     *
     * @Serializer\Expose
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $code
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     *
     * @Serializer\Expose
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var datetime $createdOn
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="createdOn", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $createdOn;

    /**
     * @var datetime $updatedOn
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(name="updatedOn", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatedOn;

    /**
     * @var formulaColors
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FormulaColor", mappedBy="formula")
     */
    private $formulaColors;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->formulaColors = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set code
     *
     * @param string $code
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    /**
     * Get code
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdOn
     *
     * @param datetime $createdOn
     */
    public function setCreatedOn($createdOn)
    {
        $this->createdOn = $createdOn;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdOn
     *
     * @return datetime 
     */
    public function getCreatedOn()
    {
        return $this->createdOn;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedOn
     *
     * @param datetime $updatedOn
     */
    public function setUpdatedOn($updatedOn)
    {
        $this->updatedOn = $updatedOn;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedOn
     *
     * @return datetime 
     */
    public function getUpdatedOn()
    {
        return $this->updatedOn;
    }

    /**
     * Add formulaColor
     *
     * @param FormulaColor $formulaColor
     */
    public function addFormulaColor(FormulaColor $formulaColor)
    {
        $this->formulaColors[] = $formulaColor;
    }

    /**
     * Get formulaColors
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getFormulaColors()
    {
        return $this->formulaColors;
    }
}
```

**FormulaColor Entity**

```
/**
 * Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\FormulaColor
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="FormulaColor")
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class FormulaColor
{

    /**
     * @var integer $formula
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Formula", inversedBy="formulaColors")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="formulaId", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $formula;

    /**
     * @var integer color
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Color", inversedBy="formulaColors")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="colorId", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $color;

    /**
     * @var decimal percentage
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=5, scale=2, nullable=false)
     */
    private $percentage;


    /**
     * Set percentage
     *
     * @param decimal $percentage
     */
    public function setPercentage($percentage)
    {
        $this->percentage = $percentage;
    }

    /**
     * Get percentage
     *
     * @return decimal 
     */
    public function getPercentage()
    {
        return $this->percentage;
    }

    /**
     * Set formula
     *
     * @param Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\Formula $formula
     */
    public function setFormula(\Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\Formula $formula)
    {
        $this->formula = $formula;
    }

    /**
     * Get formula
     *
     * @return Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\Formula 
     */
    public function getFormula()
    {
        return $this->formula;
    }

    /**
     * Set color
     *
     * @param Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\Color $color
     */
    public function setColor(\Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\Color $color)
    {
        $this->color = $color;
    }

    /**
     * Get color
     *
     * @return Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\Color 
     */
    public function getColor()
    {
        return $this->color;
    }
}
```

**Color Entity**

```
/**
 * Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\Color
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Color")
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Color
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $code
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @var string $hexColor
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hex_color", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $hexColor;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer $sortOrder
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sortOrder", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $sortOrder;

    /**
     * @var datetime $createdOn
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="createdOn", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $createdOn;

    /**
     * @var datetime $updatedOn
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updatedOn", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatedOn;

    /**
     * @var $formulaColors
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FormulaColor", mappedBy="color")
     */
    private $formulaColors;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->formulaColors = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set code
     *
     * @param string $code
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    /**
     * Get code
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set sortOrder
     *
     * @param integer $sortOrder
     */
    public function setSortOrder($sortOrder)
    {
        $this->sortOrder = $sortOrder;
    }

    /**
     * Get sortOrder
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getSortOrder()
    {
        return $this->sortOrder;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdOn
     *
     * @param datetime $createdOn
     */
    public function setCreatedOn($createdOn)
    {
        $this->createdOn = $createdOn;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdOn
     *
     * @return datetime 
     */
    public function getCreatedOn()
    {
        return $this->createdOn;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedOn
     *
     * @param datetime $updatedOn
     */
    public function setUpdatedOn($updatedOn)
    {
        $this->updatedOn = $updatedOn;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedOn
     *
     * @return datetime
     */
    public function getUpdatedOn()
    {
        return $this->updatedOn;
    }

    /**
     * Get formulaColors
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getFormulaColors()
    {
        return $this->formulaColors;
    }

    /**
     * addFormulaColors
     *
     * @param \Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\FormulaColor $formulaColor
     */
    public function addFormulaColor(\Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\FormulaColor $formulaColor)
    {
        $this->formulaColors[] = $formulaColor;
    }

    /**
     * Remove formulaColors
     *
     * @param \Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\FormulaColor $formulaColors
     */
    public function removeFormulaColor(\Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\FormulaColor $formulaColors)
    {
        $this->formulaColors->removeElement($formulaColors);
    }

    /**
     * Set hexColor
     *
     * @param string $hexColor
     * @return Color
     */
    public function setHexColor($hexColor)
    {
        $this->hexColor = $hexColor;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get hexColor
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getHexColor()
    {
        return $this->hexColor;
    }
}
```

**I also have a ColorAddEditType form**

```
class ColorAddEditType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('code', null, array(
                    'label' => 'Code'
                ))
            ->add('name', null, array(
                    'label' => 'Name'
                ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\Color'
            ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'prism_portal_adminbundle_coloraddedittype';
    }
}
```

I've also updated my code according to Ryan's response.

**FormulaColorType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('color', new ColorAddEditType());
    $builder->add('percent', 'number');
}
```

**FormulaAddEditType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('code', null, array(
                'label' => 'Code'
            ))
        ->add('name', null, array(
                'label' => 'Name'
            ));

    $builder->add('formulaColors', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new FormulaColorType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
        ));
}
```

and now I'm getting use a transformer / set data_class to null exceptions. When I change the one to null, then it says I can change the other to null. When I do that it basically says to change it back. Is it normal that I should have to set up a data transformer for something like this?

Here is the current error I'm getting:

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class
>   Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\Color, but is an instance of class
>   Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\FormulaColor. You can avoid this
>   error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view
>   transformer that transforms an instance of class
>   Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\FormulaColor to an instance of
>   Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\Color.

Comment: show your entities and your formula form. remember you can create subforms and composite forms. using the collection type should do the trick. the form component is very powerfull there is nothing you cant do.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback. I updated my post with my entities and the formula form type. I know you can embed forms but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this. It's a fairly common pattern. The tricky bit will be the Javascript, but it won't be too bad. You might need to make your numbers add to 100 using Javascript as well.

**FormulaType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('formulaColors', 'collection', array(
      'type' => new FormularColorType(),
      'allow_add' => true,
      'allow_delete' => true,
      'prototype' => true,
    ));
}
```

**FormulaColorType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('color', new ColorType()); // Or similar
    $builder->add('percent', 'number');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my post. That is kind of what I was thinking in the first place but when I play around with it I am always getting errors. Either something with setting data_class to null or using a data transformer or it expecting a certain instance type but getting a persistencecollection. Right now I'm getting an exception that I added to the original post.

Comment: ah, well turns out I had data_class set to the Color entity and not the FormulaColor entity. Although it's not rendering what I actually want it to right now it is actually rendering some form elements so that's a good start.

Comment: What I want to do is display a number field for the percentage. I've got that. However, I want to display the color name for each percentage as a label, not as an editable field. What would be a good way to do that?

Comment: Probably override the output for that field in your form template (see http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming). Output a label instead of the form widget. And make sure you set your default colors on the `Formula` - probably in the Formula constructor would make sense. It may not actually make sense to use an entity for colors. If it's a fixed set of colors that can't be changed, I'd just put the integers directly in the `Formula`.