# Display a a related entity property value as a form label in symfony

Tags: symfony

This stems from this question but my question has changed slightly: [Odd many-to-many form rendering with symfony and doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292178/odd-many-to-many-form-rendering-with-symfony-and-doctrine)

My entities are Formula one-to-many with FormulaColor many-to-one with Color.

Formula (id, code, name)
FormulaColor (formula_id, color_id, percentage)
Color (id, code, name)

A formula can have one or more colors and each color makes up a percentage of that formula.

I'm trying to make a Formula edit type that will show the percentage fields for a given formula and a label or title for each percentage field that is Color->Name for a label. I am already showing the percentage fields for a formula, but I want to label each one with the color name. How can I do this? Will I have to somehow use the querybuilder?

**I have a FormulaAddEditType that looks like this:**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('code', null, array(
                'label' => 'Code'
            ))
        ->add('name', null, array(
                'label' => 'Name'
            ));

    $builder->add('formulaColors', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new FormulaColorType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
        ));
}
```

**Then a FormulaColorType:**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('percentage', 'number', array(
            'label' => new ColorAddEditType()
        ));
}
```

**ColorAddEditType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('code', null, array(
                'label' => 'Code'
            ))
        ->add('name', null, array(
                'label' => 'Name'
            ))
    ;
}
```

**The controller action**

```
/**
 * @Route("/formulas/{id}/edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $formula = $em->getRepository('PrismPortalCommonBundle:Formula')->find($id);

    if (!$formula) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Formula entity.');
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new FormulaAddEditType(), $formula);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $em->persist($formula);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('prism_portal_admin_dashboard_index'));
        }
    }

    return array(
        'formula' => $formula,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

**I was able to get the results I want in a form event subscriber. The subscriber looks like this:**

```
class AddPercentFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        // Tells the dispatcher that you want to listen on the form.pre_set_data
        // event and that the preSetData method should be called.
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData');
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // If it's not a new Formula, then I want to show the percentage fields.
        if ($data) {
            $form->add('percentage', 'text', array(
                    'label' => $data->getColor()->getCode(),
                ));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the controller code where you create this form.

Comment: @Lighthart I've added the action from the controller.

Comment: These labels are only for existing formulas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made some guesses as to what your entity looks like, but I think this is roughly what you want, something like:

FormulaAddEditType

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $entity=$builder->getData();
    $colors=$entity->getColors());

    $builder
    ->add('code', null, array(
        'label' => 'Code'
        ))
    ->add('name', null, array(
        'label' => 'Name'
        ));

    $colors->map(function ($color) use ($builder) {
        $builder->add($color->getName()
            , null, 
            array(
                'label' => $color->getName()
                )
            )
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks lighthart, I actually was just able to get something thrown together which looks very similar to what you did except I did it with a form event subscriber (see my edited post to see exactly what I did). Do you think one method is better than the other?

Comment: I have no experience with subscribers.  If it works and you're groovy with it, then that is best.  Please post your method as your own answer, and accept that answer so other people don't spin their wheels  trying to find other solutions.

Comment: `$colors=$entity.getColors());` what?

Comment: opps. slipped into another language for a minute there.  Fixed.